# Finding the unique values of two or more mapped arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, dictionary, iterator

In my project I have three models: `Artist`, `Album`, `Genre`. Each artist has many albums and albums have many genres (all through a `many_to_many` association). I'd like to gather all of the genres of an artists album collection and filter any duplicates. So for instance I have two albums that belong to an artist:

```
artist = Artist.create(name: "John Doe")

rock = Genre.create(name: "Rock")

album_one = Album.create(name: "Album One")
album_one.genres << rock

album_two = Album.create(name: "Album Two")
album_two.genres << rock
```

If I were query these genres of both albums in my console using the following method I get this:

```
artist_albums = artist.albums

artist_albums.genres.map { |genre| genre.name }.uniq.join(', ')
=> Genre
```

I think I've come close to solving the issue. I just can't seem to retrieve the genre's name. Instead its returning the class name.

**Models**

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name

    has_many :albums, through: album_ownerships
    has_many :album_ownerships
end

class AlbumOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist
    belongs_to :album
end

class Genreship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :album
    belongs_to :genre
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name

    has_many :genres, through: :genreships
    has_many :genreships
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name
    has_many :albums, through: :genreships
    has_many :genreships
end
```

**Controller**

```
def show
  @artist = Artist.find(params[:id]
  @albums = @artist.albums
end
```

**View**

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %> 
  <%= album.genres.map { |genre| genre.name }.uniq.join(', ') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the data being retrieved. Also, as a matter of programming style, don't put code processing the data in your view. Do it in the controller, save the results in a variable, and access that in the view. You want your page to display as fast as possible, not pause as data is retrieved from the database or is crunched.

Comment: When you say *sample data* what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: When asking a question, we need to know three things: What data is being input, what code is massaging the data, and what should the output data look like after the code works on it. While you're working against a database, it helps us if we have some sort of visualization of that data. As is, your question is off-topic because you're asking for help debugging, but you didn't fulfill the requirements Stack Overflow has for that sort of question. See #1 at "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Comment: I think you have some unnecessary models, like maybe the AlbumOwnership, why should there be such a model? Can an Album belong to many Artists?

Comment: @TamerShlash The AlbumOwnership is a join table. So in turn artists have many albums

Comment: @TamerShlash I think I've come very close to figuring this out. Note the second block of code in my updated question. The only thing that I can't figure out is getting genre's name.

Comment: @CarlEdwards there is no need for a join table unless an Artist can have many Albums and an Album can belong to many Artists. If an album belongs to one artist, you should not have a join table, and instead have an `artist_id` field in the Album model.

Comment: That's indeed the case. An Artist can have many Albums and an Album can belong to many Artists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
Genre.joins(:genreships).where(genreships: { album_id: artist.albums }).uniq
```

Edit following your new inputs

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:id]
    @genres = Genre.joins(:genreships).where(genreships: { album_id: @artist.albums }).uniq
  end
end
```

And now in your view

```
<%= @genres.pluck(:name).join(', ') %>
```